# CSS Menu overlapping elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make a menu using images with a nice effect when they are hovered. I have a problem, when the elements are hovered (and the element changes the size) the hovered div will overlap other divs. Here what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="bar">
    <ul id="elements">
        <li>
            <div id="el1" class="el1">
                <img src="bar/img1.jpg" weight="120px" height="100px">
            </div>
            <div class="txt">aaa</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="el1">
                <img src="bar/img2.jpg" weight="120px" height="100px">
            </div>
            <div class="txt">bbb</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#bar {
    width:800px;
    height:65px;
    background: url("bar.png");
}
#elemente ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#elements li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
#elements li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the elements that aren't being hovered over to shift to the left/right?

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

```css
#bar {
    width:800px;
    height:65px;
    background: url("bar.png");
}
#elemente ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#elements li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
#elements li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: Please use this solution

Comment: Hi Bala, please try to include some sort of explanation along with your code so the OP and community knows what you changed and why.

Comment: Hi Bala, your suggestion unfortunately didn't do the trick for me. As Adam Marshal said before, I need that the elements in the left and right of the hovered element to shift left/right.

Answer (score 0):

the transform makes it difficult, you could try following:

```
#elements li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-30px);
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

This way the elements won't overlap each other, because we're making sure we have enough space around the element.

I don't see a way to move both left and right with just a hover, JavaScript would be the solution to that if that's what you're looking for.
Something like this perhaps:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#elements li').hover(function() {
    $('#elements').css('margin-left', '-15px');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the margin
    $('#elements').css('margin-left', '');
  });
});
</script>
```